# On the topic of dot notation struture of programming and some basic clarifications of OOP

Tags: java, oop

I would like to know if my understanding of OOP concepts are correct and if I could have a few things addressed for clarity. An object is based off the template details of the class, and these details are programmed in the beginning of the project, after the class is first created. These details provide the general attributes or outline of what the objects will take on, and these are called instance member variables. Then you can start intertwining or ACTING upon those instance members with methods or functions. But first one must create an instantiate of the class, called an object, which is like a big collection of instance members. Once that is done you can start applying these methods which access/modify the original instance variables, which always stay constant but at the same time instances of that class can always access and modify them. Modifying them is done by using a series of method. Is this correct?

One thing I truly don't understand at all is DOT notation, does the dot call the method to the object and somehow merge them? and then after being called you can decide what to put in the methods parameters? is that what is meant by passing in values, meaning you set values into them once they are called by using the dot in between the instantiation of the object and the method.

Thank you

Comment: "Is this correct?" It's hard to follow what you are asking, but terminology like "template details", "intertwining" etc is not correct, or at least not well-recognized.

Comment: There are field accesses and there are method invocations. Which one confuses you? There are also qualified names and inner class instantiation. Are you asking about those?

Comment: DOT notation is not a thing. The `.` character **is** used in Java source code, in the statements I've listed in my previous comment. Which of those is confusing you? Please clarify.

Comment: Could you explain what field accesses and method invocations are. Is that when the dot is placed between and object and a class. The dot invokes the method onto all the instance member vars of objects class.

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation allows access to members of a particular class. Meaning you can use dot notation to access value of fields of a particular class or use the same dot notation to call a methods/constructor of a particular class. In short that's what it does.

Comment: Thank you!
To clarify, is a field just another name for all the instance member variables that an object possesses from a its class? 
And by applying the dot in between an object of a certain class and a method it's like saying "Ok, apply this method/function to all the instance member variables of that objects' class", or maybe more precisely, only the instance members which the method was <i>designed</i> to be able to take in and mutate, like ints or doubles.